# How to filter greater than or is null?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I want to filter "greater than or equal to", I can use `gte`:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(mydatetimefield__gte=mydate)
```

Likewise, if I want to filter "is none/null", I can use `isnull`:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(mydatetimefield__isnull=mydate)
```

How can I combine these to filter for "greater than or equal to or is null", so the above filter would return both objects if i) `mydatetimefield >= mydate`, and ii) `mydatetimefield == null`?

Answer (score 6):

you use `Q` statements to perform `OR` logic

```
from django.db.models import Q

qry = Q(mydatetimefield=None) | Q(mydatetimefield__gte=mydate)

MyModel.objects.filter(qry)
```

In keeping with the spirit of Willem Van Onsems alternative suggestion

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(mydatetimefield__lt=mydate)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q), and use a bitwise or (`|`) operator to specify a condition that should satisfiy one of the two subconditions:

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q(mydatetimefield__gte=mydate) |
    Q(mydatetimefield=None)
)
```

or you can negate the `__lt` lookup:

```
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(mydatetimefield__lt=mydate))
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley: well the `Q` conditions are swapped :p